# Why is `root` keep staying null?

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-tree

I have a very basic binary tree

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class ExprTree {
    // Data member
    private ExprTreeNode root; // reference to root node
    private String input;
    private Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    // Constructor
    public ExprTree() {
//      root = new ExprTreeNode(key, leftPtr, rightPtr)
    }
    // Expression tree manipulation methods
    public void build() {
        System.out.println("Please enter a prefix sequence. avoid using spaces!");
        input = s.nextLine();

        for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); ++i) {
            addToTree(root, input.charAt(i));
        }       
    }

    public void expression() {
    }

    public float evaluate() {
        return 0;

    }

    public void clear() {

    }

    public void showStructure(ExprTreeNode t) {
        if(t == null) // no more
            return;
        System.out.println(t.getKey() + "-> ");
        showStructure(t.getLeft());
        showStructure(t.getRight());
    }

    private void showSubTrees(ExprTreeNode p, int leven) {

    }

    private void addToTree(ExprTreeNode t, char key) {
        if(t == null) { // no more
            t = new ExprTreeNode(key, null, null);
            return;
        } 
            addToTree(t.getLeft(), key);
            addToTree(t.getRight(), key);
    }

    public ExprTreeNode getRoot() {
        return root;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExprTree t = new ExprTree();
        t.build();
        t.showStructure(t.getRoot());
    }
}
```

And the tree node class:

```
public class ExprTreeNode {
    // Data memebers
    private char key;
    private ExprTreeNode left, 
                         right;
    // Constructor
    public ExprTreeNode(char key, ExprTreeNode leftPtr, ExprTreeNode rightPtr) {
        this.key = key;
        left = leftPtr;
        right = rightPtr;
    }

    public char getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(char key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public ExprTreeNode getLeft() {
        return left;
    }
    public void setLeft(ExprTreeNode left) {
        this.left = left;
    }
    public ExprTreeNode getRight() {
        return right;
    }
    public void setRight(ExprTreeNode right) {
        this.right = right;
    }
}
```

In this line:

```
        for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); ++i) {
            addToTree(root, input.charAt(i));
        }
```

Every time I call `addToTree` with `root`, the debugegr shows that `root` is null,

even though the first time I called `addToTree` has alloced root, and the debugger shows so.

Why is it keep staying null?

Comment: You're returning an uninitialized `root` object directly from the `getRoot()` method.

Comment: @Lion Im allocate it in the `addToTree` method

Answer (score 1):

You commented out the line in

```
public ExprTree() {
    //  root = new ExprTreeNode(key, leftPtr, rightPtr); 
    // just use null for both left and right ptr
}
```

so `root` is `null`.

Remember that java is pass by value, so

```
private void addToTree(ExprTreeNode t, char key) {
    if(t == null) { // no more
        t = new ExprTreeNode(key, null, null);
        return;
    } 
        addToTree(t.getLeft(), key);
        addToTree(t.getRight(), key);
}
```

called with

```
 addToTree(root, input.charAt(i));
```

`t` has the same reference as `root`, ie. `null`, but isn't a reference to the variable `root`. So all you are doing is re-assigning a local variable.

Comment: Java is passing by value? really? I was sure it's passing by referece.. is there any way to pass by reference?

Comment: @user1798362 No, there isn't. Instead, assign the root, left and right directly instead of calling a method.

Comment: The problem comes again at t.getLeft() ect.

How can I allocate memory through a function?

Comment: @user Redesign your method. Use `t.setLeft(someValue)`.